# Xamarin Stacklayout not being populated

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I have a Stacklayout on screen and it's populated at different times with labels from the code-behind.

The problem is, I have this one method that doesn't populate the Stacklayout. It uses the same identical code as the other methods. It runs through the code successfully but it just does not show on screen.

'readout' is the Stacklayout.

```
public async void HandleNFC(string convertedtag)
{
    PeopleLocationsForUserRoot peoplelocationforuser = await WebDataAccess.GetPeopleLocationForUser("ConroyJ", 1);

    Label label1 = new Label { Text = "Successfully clocked out @ " + convertedtag, TextColor = Color.Black };

   readOut.Children.Add(label1);
   DisplayAlert("NFC", convertedtag, "cancel");

}
```

Comment: try using Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread() to force the update to run on the UI thread

Comment: Does the DisplayAlert trigger? Does the stack layout hold any other views at that point? Try clearing it or changing it's background property to make sure you are looking at the correct SL.

Comment: @irreal Yes the DisplayAlert is working and there is only one view.

Comment: @Jason It requires an action, what do I use?

Comment: Thing is, the method is called from different places like I said. I don't see why it would work for some places and not others.

Comment: The name of the method "HandleNFC" strongly implies it could be called from a background thread. But in that case I'd expect it to crash, not ignore the change. Try Device.BegininvokeOnMainThread(()=> { //all your UI code goes here });

Comment: Is the issue being caused because I'm creating a new instance of MainPage in the drop app (on handle of new NFC tag).

Comment: That's not the right approach.  You need to figure out how to get a reference to the instance of MainPage that's already being displayed.

Comment: @Jason You're right, but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a Forms app, you can get a reference to your MainPage like this

```
  App.Current.MainPage
```

you will also need to cast it correctly in order to call a custom method

```
  var main = (MyMainPageType) App.Current.MainPage;
  main.HandleNFC(data);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for that. I couldn't find this anywhere!